# How add XML2CSV processor to Keboola components?

Tags: json, xml, export-to-csv, documentation, processor

I would like to use the XML2CSV processor to be able to convert XML files to JSON and then to CSV format.
The problem is that in Keboola Components there is not this component. The only way how to implement the tool is probably via API. Is anyone familiar with it please?
The documentation for the XML2CSV processor: https://components.keboola.com/components/kds-team.processor-xml2csv

I will be happy to convert XML files in SnowFlake table :)

Comment: Did you see following : https://help.keboola.com/components/applications/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.